# MVC - DropDownListFor Enum - Set Default Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, enums

My Dropdown works properly with following code :-

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StopMonth, Enum.GetNames(typeof(Models.InputMonths)).Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e }), new { @class = "form-control"})

public enum InputMonths
    {
        January,
        February,
        March,
        April,
        May,
        June,
        July,
        August,
        September,
        October,
        November,
        December
    }
```

But when it is displayed in View, I need DropDown to display `---Select Month---` as default value.
So that i can check required validation in jQuery Script.

How to do this?

Comment: Is `StopMonth` nullable?

Comment: yes..can set `null` to `StopMonth`.

Comment: You can user the overload that has the 3rd parameter as "--Select month--" [Refer documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703567(v=vs.118).aspx). Not sure, but I think you also need to set the `Value` of `SelectList` as well as the `Text` property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add value to your enum

```
public enum InputMonths {
    January = 1,
    February = 2,
    March = 3,
    April = 4,
    May = 5,
    .
    .
    .        
}
```

Then decorate your Model with:

```
[Required]
[Range(1, 12, ErrorMessage = "Select a month"))]
public StopMonth StopMonth { get; set; }
```

And finally:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.StopMonth,
    Enum.GetNames(typeof(Models.InputMonths))
        .Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e }),
    "-- Select a month --",
    new { @class = "form-control"})
```